# how to install packages with pip?

Tags: python

I have installed pip this way.
1.download from https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pip
2.extract it in d:\pip-1.5.6\
3.install
d:\Python27\python d:\pip-1.5.6\setup.py install.
There are pips in my directory(site-packages).

[image]

When to install  flask ,i get error message "ImportError: No module named pip" ,what's the reason,and how to solve it?

[image]

Comment: You have a problem in the pip install, look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4750806/1982962), possible duplicate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first you can follow this steps :

```
  Run virtualenv and create your virtualenv    
  install pip & setuptools into this virtualenv
```

if still you have the problem i think its a bug and you can see  https://github.com/pypa/virtualenv/issues/564 references http://bugs.python.org/issue20621 !